# Load the php file Content with in php

Tags: php

I'm try to access the php file, when i use the

Below Code

```
if(is_file('template1.php')){

     $return = file_get_contents("template1.php?content=1");

}
```

it'showing the ERROR : failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Thank You

Comment: Is the file in a different directory? It does not exist where it is looking for it.

Comment: Try to use full path like `http://example.com/template1.php?content=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to get the **content generated by PHP**, if so use:

```
$yourData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/template1.php?content=1');
```

Otherwise if you want to get the **source code of the PHP file**, it's the same as a .txt file:

```
$yourData = file_get_contents('/template1.php?content=1');
```

file_get_contents() will not work if your server has **allow_url_fopen** turned off. Most shared web hosts have it turned off by default due to security risks. Also, in PHP6, the **allow_url_fopen** option will no longer exist and all functions will act as if it is permenantly set to off. So this is a very bad method to use.

Your best option to use if you are accessing the file through http is cURL

Comment: Thank You for suggest, now i'm using cURL

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` is used to read something from the filesystem, or an absolute URL. You would have to specify the full URL to the file you want to read i.e. http://www.example.com/template1.php?content=1. Or if you are reading a file on the filesystem you would have to specify a path to that file.

I am assuming you are trying to read a file on your website so you would have to do something like `file_get_contents("path/to/file.php")` or better yet, just include the file using include (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0):

Starts the filename with `./` if it's in the current directory of the current file, or `../` if it's in the parent directory. Please give these a try, if there's no problem on your syntax:

```
if (is_file('/template1.php')) {
    $return = file_get_contents("/template1.php?content=1");
}
```

or

```
if (is_file('./template1.php')) {
    $return = file_get_contents("./template1.php?content=1");
}
```

or

```
if (is_file('../template1.php')) {
    $return = file_get_contents("../template1.php?content=1");
}
```